What would be the name for the fallacy leaving out important supporting evidence from an opponents argument?
I know if one misrepresents an opponents position to make it look weaker than it is that’s known as a straw-man fallacy.  I’m not sure if leaving out important supporting evidence would qualify as a straw-man as I don’t know if it would qualify as misrepresenting the opponents position.  I still think leaving out important supporting evidence should qualify as a fallacy as it can make an opponents position seem weaker than it really is even if it accurately represents the conclusion.
Example:
Person A starts off by discussing how they heard they heard rumors of flying bears on a remote island, from the locals.  Next person A discusses how this lead a team of researchers to this remote island to investigate.  Person A then presents physical evidence of the flying bears on this remote island, including DNA evidence that confirms that they are indeed in the bear clade.  Person A also presents peer reviewed scientific papers on the flying bears, which all conclude that this island has flying bears.  Person A also discusses how other teams of researchers have visited the island and come to the same conclusion that the island has flying bears.  Lastly Person A takes Person B to the island to see the flying bears.
Person B then responds by simply saying that rumors aren’t always true and that to claim that there’s a remote island with flying bears would require extra ordinary evidence.
I’m not sure if Person B would be straw-manning Person As position given that Person B accurately represented the argument of Person A and Person A did start off by talking about rumors, however it still feels like Person B is misrepresenting the argument of Person A by making it sound like rumors were the entire argument of Person A instead of just the introduction, with Person A giving a lot more supporting evidence for the flying bears after discussing the rumors.
Is there a name for this fallacy and if so what is it?

This is called fallacy of suppressed evidence:"one commits the fallacy when one presents evidence or an argument for a position but leaves out (or suppresses) relevant evidence that would weaken or show false one's conclusion." In American courts, suppression of exculpatory (favorable to the defendant) evidence is considered prosecutorial misconduct, and the requirement to provide it to the defense is called Brady disclosure (after the Supreme Court case that introduced it in 1963).

“Straw man” is different. In the straw man fallacy you claim that your opponent claims X, which he doesn’t claim at all, then you prove that X is false, and therefore your opponent is wrong. Which he isn’t. Because he never claimed the false X.

Fallacies are failures in deductive reasoning.
Essentially your deductive arguments follow the form of implications so "if A then B". Then you'd show A and conclude B. So all fallacies are essentially "non sequitur" (does not follow), meaning they refer to an error in the implication so that B does not actually follow from A.
Now these are relations of certainty. If there is just one counter example to your implication then the implication is fallacious, because it does not actually follow that B if A. While conversely just because your implication is fallacious, does not mean that it would be wrong all the time (fallacy fallacy), just that it is not correct ALL THE TIME.
Now the problem is that, in the real world, most if not all of our knowledge is NOT in fact based on deductive reasoning, but rather on inductive reasoning or a mixture of those. So rather than having universal rules and deriving particulars from it, we more often than not compile universal rules by extrapolating from observations of repeating patterns and then check via deduction what this would imply to roughly confirm our intuitions.
But while this process is at the heart of most of our attempts to gain any knowledge at all and is quite successful at doing so, it's actually fallacious and science is "wrong". Or more precisely it's an assumption not a certainty, a constant work in progress, rather than an eternal universal truth.
An illustrative example for the problem of induction is the hypothesis that "I didn't die the last decades, I didn't die today, so I'm not going to die tomorrow either". You can both see how it works surprisingly well most of the time, but how it's pretty inevitably going to fail someday.
So if you hunt for fallacies you should first be aware of what the proposed implication is.
So in this case it's probably about some sort of epistemology. So in other words "what provides conclusive evidence for knowledge". In that case, hearsay, eye-witnesses, expert witnesses, data gathering and analysis, single source, multiple sources etc.
Now factually none of them are ultimately conclusive, but as absolute skepticism doesn't get you anywhere you'd likely at some point draw a line and no longer compare it to absolute certainty, but to the probabilities of other methods of knowledge gathering, where it very likely ends up being the one-eyed king of the blinds.
Though juggling with probabilities is a lot more sketchy than doing it with certainties and while you can make stronger or weaker arguments and check their likelihood, their ultimate truth value would be confirmed by actual experiments and can only be hypothesized.
So you could apply the concept to inductive reasoning, but it would lack a lot of the punch that it has in deductive reasoning, as the "one counter example shatters the theory" does not longer apply. On the contrary even if it has a 0.1% failure rate, which can result in a lot more than 1 counter example, that's still pretty good in many domains.
Now with regards to your example. To whom is B saying that? Like if he addresses an uninformed audience, that's a straw man argument, he takes shots at the probability of rumors, but that's not the actual argument, but just the starting point of the quest which progressed much further than that.
So even if he is successful in making a case for discrediting rumors as a source of information, that falls flat at discrediting all the other more reliable sources of information provided.
While if he is still arguing exclusively with A, that might just be laziness in terms of not wanting to iterate through the entire list of evidence but instead give a blatant refusal of "I'm not convinced by any of that". Which... is fine. That's not necessarily a fallacy. In fact if someone told you about flying bears, you'd likely question their sanity. And if they came at you with peer-reviewed science about it, you'd likely question the sanity of people having a loony as peer. And even if they had direct evidence it could still be  a hallucination from a gas lack. And if you were specifically brought to the island, that could all be a big show just for you.
So it's not unreasonable to be skeptic about extraordinary claims. So that's unfortunately not as clear cut as true/false, but comes down to ranking credibility, probabilities and personal credence.
So TL;DR depending on the situation it could be an attempt at bad faith rhetoric but it doesn't have to be more fallacy and fallacies don't really apply here.
